# Sql Transaction - SQL Server or C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

Am I right in saying that from a performance perspective, sql transactions are far better within a stored procedure than code?

At the moment I use most of my transactions in stored procs but sometimes I use code for more complex routines - which obviously I keep to a minimum as much as possible.

It's just that there was a complex routine that required too many "variables" that writing the sql transaction in c# was far easier than using SQL Server. It's a fine line between code readability and performance.

Any ideas?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net

Comment: As an aside: it's store*d* procedures - as *stored* in SQL Server - not store procedure - just a nitpick....

Comment: Oh yes. Use to short hand "store proc", thanks marc_s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The performance varies; a `SqlTransaction` can have less overhead than a `TransactionScope`, especially if the `TransactionScope` decides it needs to get entangled with DTC. But I wouldn't expect a *vast* difference between `SqlTransaction` and a `BEGIN TRAN`, except for the extra round trip. However, `TransactionScope` is still fast, and is the most convenient option for encapsulating multiple operations in a transaction, as the ambient transaction does not need to be manually associated with the command each time.

Perhaps a better (and more significant) factor is the [isolation-level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122.aspx). `TransactionScope` defaults to the highest (serializable). Lower isolation levels allow morefor less blocking (but at the risk of non-repeatable reads, etc). IIRC a TSQL transaction defaults to one of the lower levels. But the isolation level can be tweaked for all 3 options.

Comment: I'll be honest and say that I have almost always used transactions in store procs and not very often in c# ado.net. As such the TransactionScope is new to me and I'm glad you mentioned this. Looks like I need to read about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm for `TransactionScope`. As per Marc, use a factory method on your `TransactionScope` to drop the isolation level to `READ COMMITTED` for most common usages I can think of.

Note that you can use both SQL transactions AND `TransactionScope` - the SQL `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT TRAN` will have little effect on `TransactionScope` (other than incrementing / decrementing `@@TRANCOUNT`) - this way if you do need to call the same SQL Sproc elsewhere, e.g. from an adhoc query that you will still get the benefit of a transaction.

The benefit of `TransactionScope` IMO is that it will manage DTC for you if you DO need to do 2 phase commit (e.g. Multiple databases, Queues or other XA transactions). And with SQL 2005 and later, it works with the [Lightweight Transaction Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155941/transactionscope-has-it-gotten-better), so DTC won't be required e.g. if all accesses are to the one database, one connection at a time.

Comment: Now that I have read more on TransactionScope and indeed Isolation levels, I'm so glad I raised this question. I wouldn't have understood your comments 5-10 mins earlier :) but do now. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction management in the code (read c#) is an option and to be followed for managing transactions over multiple data source or system. For managing transaction for a single database, the management at the server end will be always simpler. But if you think that the code might need to cater to a scenario where multiple data-sources get added in the transaction, keep the transactions in the code level.

Comment: Good point about the multiple databases. Most if not all transactions I use are indeed with one database... so perhaps structure all transactions with sql server. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in that case you can do it at the server end.

Answer (score 1):

I belive that the store procedure will have better performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you write SQL Transactions in C# and use ADO.Net or similar to execute them then they are probably less efficient because SQL will cache the query plan for a stored procedure (which is also now the case for Entity Framework - though still not as quick as proc I don't think) so really you should probably be doing it the other way round - complex procedures in SQL to get the caching benefits (if only it were that simple...)

Comment: Yes Sql Transactions in C# and using ADO .NET. I forgot about caching. Thanks

Comment: Having said this I am now not sure whether it wouldn't cache the query plan for the C# query too, there is some trick to getting the EF to cache (I think it's having fixed column lengths or something) so that may apply to ADO.Net queries too - however I believe this only applies in SQL 2008

Comment: Query plans are cached and re-used without needing stored procedures

Comment: @marc thanks for the info - further to that then why was there so much discussion around EF1 not doing it? and why does EF4 have functionality to turn it on and off?

Comment: @EF1 - I'd need to see the specific reference; that might mean the internal EF query compilation (which is separate to TSQL place re-use), or it might have been the foobar with things like strings as parameters causing cache miss (i.e. same query with a varchar(11) param and a varchar(5) parameter, because the value in the query was 11 vs 5 chars long, if you see what I mean)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what application.

But I will say that in most cases it is best to surprised to have logic in the database. A very advantageous also to have business logic in the databse, is that then it will be the same even if you have riders a WinForms version and a web, or whatever

But if you're talking about the CLR in SQL. The negative with this, it becomes much more difficult for a DBA to find any errors or something about. performance.

Comment: Good point. I read about CLR performs better BUT as oyu say finding errors is a major issue.