# How to implement single SQL transaction for multiple ObjectContexts in EF4

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a fairly big database with tables created for different business modules.

We decided to create different edmx-files for different modules respectively.

However, how can I prevent the usage of MSDTC when trying to implement a TransactionScope for a logical action that will incur writing to multiple tables in different edmx? Again, the underlying database is the same, I wouldn't want to use MSDTC for this scenario.

Is there any way to pass in an opened SQL connection with active transaction?

Thanks for help in advance.

Regards,
William

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do *everything* in EF.

Answer (score 2):

`TransactionScope` enlists the MSDTC when the databases are different and/or the connection strings are different.

Rick Strahl has a [great article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jul/14/LINQ-to-SQL-and-Transactions) on this (his perspective is LINQ to SQL, but it's applicable to EF).  The money paragraphs:

> TransactionScope is a high level Transaction wrapper that makes it
>   real easy to wrap any code into a transaction without having to track
>   transactions manually. Traditionally TransactionScope was a .NET
>   wrapper around the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) but it’s
>   functionality has expanded somewhat. One concern is that the DTC is
>   rather expensive in terms of resource usage and it requires that the
>   DTC service is actually running on the machine (yet another service
>   which is especially bothersome on a client installation).
>
> However, recent updates to TransactionScope and the SQL Server Client
>   drivers make it possible to use TransactionScope class and the ease of
>   use it provides without requiring DTC as long as you are running
>   against a single database and with a single consistent connection
>   string. In the example above, since the transaction works with a
>   single instance of a DataContext, the transaction actually works
>   without involving DTC. This is in SQL Server 2008.

See also this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155941/transactionscope-has-it-gotten-better) where I found the link to Rick's blog.

So if you're connecting to the same database and are using the same connection string, the DTC should not be involved.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all replies above!

by the way, just managed to find a solution which is to use EntityConnection and EntityTransaction explicitly. A sample is like this:

```
    string theSqlConnStr = "data source=TheSource;initial catalog=TheCatalog;persist security info=True;user id=TheUserId;password=ThePassword";

    EntityConnectionStringBuilder theEntyConnectionBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    theEntyConnectionBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    theEntyConnectionBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = theConnectionString;
    theEntyConnectionBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/";

    using (EntityConnection theConnection = new EntityConnection(theEntyConnectionBuilder.ToString()))
    {
        theConnection.Open();
        theET = null;

        try
        {
            theET = theConnection.BeginTransaction();

            DataEntities1 DE1 = new DataEntities1(theConnection);
            //DE1 do somethings...

            DataEntities2 DE2 = new DataEntities2(theConnection);
            //DE2 do somethings...

            DataEntities3 DE3 = new DataEntities3(theConnection);
            //DE3 do somethings...

            theET.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (theET != null) { theET.Rollback(); }
        }
        finally
        {
            theConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

with explicit use of EntityConnection & EntityTransaction, I can achieve the sharing of single connection and transaction for multiple ObjectContexts for a single database, yet without the need to incur the usage of MSDTC.

Hope this info is helpful. Gd luck!!